# enabling everyone write permission on a host within active directory using powershell

Tags: powershell

As part of an experiment I'm conducting regarding a misconfiguration that allows an attack that called shadow credentials, I created a network that has a DC and a windows client.

The client is connected to the DC and the computer object appears in the active directory.

I'm trying to enable a specific setting using Powershell, but I'm not sure where to search for that. I tried to search through several forums, and some pointed me to the `Set-Acl` cmdlet, but I was unable to find a way to enable the setting I want.

[image]

As shown in the image above, I opened the Computers tab under the Domain, and in there I opened the Properties of the domain.

Under Properties, I chose the Security settings, and within the Security settings I'm trying to add the permission to write to the group "Everyone".

I tried to search through the web, and some forums indicate that its a permission that can be found under the Properties of the object. However, I tried to browse through the object properties, and could not find any related property.

Furthermore, I tried to search how to modify a group, as this is a group related to the object.

Thanks in advance, any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Go to the top of the ADUC consoel and enable `Advanced Features` in options. All the tabs will then be visible.

Comment: Cant do that, it should be a part of a script, therefore i  need it to be done through powershell and not through the gui.

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question and post the code you're trying. Powershell has `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` commands that can manipulate object permissions

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution after a few days of debugging

```
$hostname = "Host"

#extreact domain information
$dom = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()            
$root = $dom.GetDirectoryEntry()            
          
#search through ldap the indomain as set before   
$search = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$root            
$search.Filter = "(Name=$hostname)"            
$search.SizeLimit = 3000            
$result = $search.FindOne()            
 
#set security object 
$object = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()                      
$sec = $object.ObjectSecurity            
            
## set the rights and control type to a generic write            
$act = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow        
$adrights = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]::GenericWrite            
            
# set the sid of the 'Everyone' security group                       
$everyone = New-Object Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ([Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WorldSid, $null)
$sec.SetGroup($everyone)
$sid = $everyone      

# apply rule            
$newrule = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule -ArgumentList ($sid), $adrights, $act          
$sec.AddAccessRule($newrule)            
$object.CommitChanges()
```